# Arduino Lightbulb Control

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am completely new to arduinos, and I am trying to run a lightbulb-style apparatus off of an arduino uno, and I need it to only operate on a certain time interval that I can adjust according to the situation. I believe that there is an internal time function in the arduino that counts in milliseconds. All i need it to do is turn on after a set amount of time, and then turn off after about a minute. How would I go about setting up the code for this?

Comment: [This](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer/) may get you started.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too broad. Please read [ask]. The usual way to learn things from scratch is to acquire information through books, tutorials and exercises with increasing difficulty until you know enough to solve your problem. if you have one particular problem with implementing your project then feel free to post here. but we cannot provide full tailored tutorials for every hobby project. especially not with the little information provided

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **millis()** function to get the current arduino operational time in milliseconds. Then compare it in the next loop(). You probably don't care what the real time is, just the relative time since the last time you checked or did something. You can create a variable to store the last event time and compare the current time to that.

Be aware that millis() may be quite large if your program runs for a long time so you should use an **unsigned long type**, otherwise the value may roll over the top bit and become interpreted as a negative number (this is a common problem).